# Passing list as argument in pydblite

Tags: python, list, in-memory-database, nosql

I've been trying to figure out how to pass a list of values as an individual parameter for pydblite.insert(*args). Each value from the list 'temp' and 'keys' must be an individual parameter for both the .insert() and .create() function respectively.

```
def copyToMemory(self, table, items):
    db = Base(table + ".pdl")

    if not (db.exists()):
        keys = ""
        for key, val in items[0].items(): keys += key + ', '
        #db.create(keys)

    db.open()
    for i in items:
        temp = []
        for val in i.itervalues():
            temp += val
        #db.insert(temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `db.create()`, construct a list of the keys and pass them as unpacked arguments like this:

```
db.create(*items[0].keys())
```

Since `items` is a list of dictionaries, you can simply use `dict.keys()` to get a list of the keys using the first item in the list. This list of keys is then unpacked to pass *positional* arguments to the `create()` function. For reference see [* in function calls](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-42).

Because `dict.keys()` is unordered, the above assumes that you do not particularly care about the order of the fields in the table.

For `db.insert()` you can pass an unpacked dictionary using `**`:

```
for item in items:
    db.insert(**item)
```

See [** in function calls](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-43). This will pass the arguments to the function as keyword arguments. Note that the order does not matter - the fields in the table will be properly associated with the corresponding item from the dictionary.